# Why does the default font for a WinForm only change when display settings is set to "Medium (125%)?

Tags: winforms, windows-7, font-size

When the Display Settings is set to either Small or Large the default font for a WinForm is set to Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt. And everything on the form scales properly. However, when it is set to Medium it changes the default font to Microsoft Sans Serif, 7.8pt, which causes various breaking issues on the form.

Is there a specific reason why the font's size only changes on the Medium setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by default if you go past Medium (anything more than 125%) then Windows starts to help and emulates a video adapter set at 96 dots per inch.  Same as Small.  This works by Windows letting the program actually draw into an in-memory bitmap and rescaling the bitmap before blitting it to the screen.  This is an appcompat feature and the result is in general not considered pretty, particularly text becomes 'fuzzy'.  It does however help keep the program usable on very high resolution screens and prevents the main window from having the size of a postage stamp.  Disabling this feature is the subject of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034), otherwise the exact opposite of what you are looking for.

It works this way because 125% scaling has been around for a long time already, at least as far back as 2001 with the XP release.  So programs are expected to know how to deal with it.  Enabling automatic DPI scalling at 125% is not an option.